# how to extract service names out of file and save them in clean version in file?

Tags: command-line

i try to figure out how to extract all service names out of /etc/services and send them to text file
sort them alphabetically
remove any duplicates
get rid of any blank lines and unnecessary spaces
and have line count

Comment: Please [edit] and add what you have so far.

Comment: I'm writing that because this sounds horribly like an assignment and we're not a scripting service here. In fact all you need is `sed`, `sort`, `bash` redirection and `wc`. Any real question which shows at least a bit effort is very welcome!

Comment: i will admit and apologize for that, it is assignment for my linux class i'm taking online. i tried to figure out on my own answer for that but all i have its errors and not proper output. i will show you some of my output but please dont laugh at me, all i ask its to show direction not complete commands

Comment: @Soulrelic Nobody laughs at you (please take my sincere apologies if that's how it looks like, that was in no way our intention), but we can't show you where you're wrong if you don't show us what you've tried and what errors you got. We're happy to help you and explain extensively!

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/services` looks like this:

```bsh
# Network services, Internet style
#
# (more comments)

tcpmux    1/tcp     # TCP port service multiplexer
echo      7/tcp
...
discard   9/tcp     sink null
discard   9/udp     sink null
...
ssh       22/tcp    # SSH Remote Login Protocol
...
```

That is, there are

- lines that consist only of a comment
- lines with trailing comments
- empty lines
- duplicates in the first column

To remove all of them, the following command is *one* possible way:

```bsh
awk '!/^\s*$/ && !/^\s*#/ {print $1}' /etc/services | sort -u | cat -n
```

#### Output

```
 1  acr-nema
 2  afbackup
 3  afmbackup
 4  afpovertcp
 5  afs3-bos
 6  afs3-callback
 7  afs3-errors
...
```

#### Explanation

```bsh
awk '!/^\s*$/ && !/^\s*#/ {print $1}' /etc/services
```

In general, `awk` reads a given file (or stdin) and then executes the following for each line:

```bsh
condition_for_a_line { commands_when_condition_is_met }
```

We use `!/^\s*$/ && !/^\s*#/` as the condition which means *line is not empty* and *line doesn't start with a comment*. When both conditions are met, the first column `$1` is printed. This gives us all first columns of the file without empty and comment lines.

```bsh
sort -u
```

This sorts the data and eliminates duplicates in one go.

```bsh
cat -n
```

Simply adds line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my `sed` solution:

```bsh
</etc/services sed '/^\w/!d;s/\s.*//' | sort -u >out
```

<sup>`sed '…' file` instead of `<file sed '…'` is possible but not preferable, as [Stéphane Chazelas explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/246819).</sup>

This will first eliminate every line beginning with something else than a word character, then delete everything from every line beginning with the first whitespace character, then sort alphabetically and eliminate duplicate lines and finally redirect the output into the file `out`.

To get a line count of this file, I'd use `wc`:

```bsh
<out wc -l
```

#### Explanations

- `</etc/services` – let `bash` open the specified file and assigns its content to stdin, it doesn't matter if this redirection is placed before or after the command, you could even do `>out sed '…' <in` if you like
- `sed '…'` – let `sed` execute the expressions `…`
- `/^\w/!d` – don't (`!`) `d`elete every line beginning (`^`) with a `w`ord character, but every line that doesn't match this criterion
- `s/\s.*//` – in every line, `s`ubstitute the first match of a white`s`pace character and everything (`.*`) that follows with nothing (= delete it)
- `command1 | command2` – let `bash` assign `command1`'s stdout to `command2`'s stdin
- `sort -u` – let `sort` sort the lines alphabetically and output only the first of an equal run (`-u` or `--unique`)
- `>out` – let `bash` redirect the stdout to the specified file
- `wc -l` – let `wc` print the new`l`ine counts

Comment: This is cool. I admit I always stumble when I see redirection at unexpected places, i.e. _before_ the actual command instead of _after_ them.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{print $1}' /etc/services | grep -v # | uniq | sort > yourFile
```

Comment: Wrong order of commands. Put `uniq` _after_ `sort`. And the `grep` will also remove lines with trailing comments.

Comment: `sort -u` is also available.

Comment: You probably meant `grep -v \#`, otherwise this command line doesn't work at all, but even then there are still empty lines as well as double entries in the output – did you test your solution?

Comment: @dessert Even `grep -v \#` won't help. I have lines like `ssh 22/tcp # SSH …` and they would be filtered out.

Comment: dessert, tcsh. For bash grep -v '#'